# LOM - RDF binding

Tags: metadata, rdf, semantic-web

Im trying to expose some learning objects into the semantic web.

I found out that the namespace used for this is "lom= http://ltsc.ieee.org/rdf/lomv1p0/lom#".

I want to get the RDF definition of all the properties defined in this namespace.

for example, lom:educational property, but I candt find it anywhere.

When I put one of this URN in the browser, It leads me to a 404.

Anyone knows where I can find it?

Regards, and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

There's a Wikipedia article on [Learning Object Metadata (LOM)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Learning_object_metadata) that might be useful as an overview or introduction.

[IEEE P1484.12.4™/D1
Draft Recommended Practice for Expressing IEEE
Learning Object Metadata Instances Using the
Dublin Core Abstract Model](http://dublincore.org/moinmoin-wiki-archive/educationwiki/attachments/LOM-DCAM-newdraft.pdf)  mentions two namespaces related to LOM, though these aren't quite the same as the namespace you mentioned, and neither is dereferenceable:

```
lom    http://ltsc.ieee.org/rdf/lomv1p0/terms# The LOM terms namespace
lomvoc http://ltsc.ieee.org/rdf/lomv1p0/vocab# The LOMv1.0 vocabulary namespace
```

The [Draft Standard for Learning Object Metadata](http://ltsc.ieee.org/wg12/files/LOM_1484_12_1_v1_Final_Draft.pdf) describes the LOM schema structure, and may be useful for determining what a given term means.

There is a now-defunct [IEEE Learning Object Metadata RDF binding](http://kmr.nada.kth.se/static/ims/md-lomrdf.html) that describes an RDF vocabulary for the LOM terms.  It contains link to the group that superseded it, but it's dead now (the link;  I don't know about the group).  The wayback machine has [an archived version](http://web.archive.org/web/20130116085915/http://dublincore.org/educationwiki/DCMIIEEELTSCTaskforce), though.

Answer (score 0):

Recently, we did a research on this context and designed a full conversion of IEEE LOM to the Linked Data formats (including RDF) at [here](http://www.erajabi.com/Uploads/W3CDraft.html) and published the report as W3C working draft (W3C has a working group on this subject). You can find a full instruction of this mapping there.